# What should repositories in DDD return

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I researched about repositories in DDD and found too much different thing. Everyone says different things about repositories and that made me confused.

I want to know:

1. What methods should repositories contain?
2. What should repositories definitely (or closer that) return?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For each aggregate root (AR) you should have a repository.  As a minimum the repository would probably have a `void Save(Aggregate aggregate)` and a `Aggregate Get(Guid id)` method.  The returned aggregate would always be fully constituted.

I sometimes add methods for specific use cases in order to update only certain bits of data.  For instance, something like `void Activate(Guid id)` or some such.  This is simply to avoid manipulating more data than is necessary.

Querying on a repository is usually problematic since you should typically avoid querying your domain.  For such scenarios my recommendation is to use a *query mechanism* that is closer to the data and in a more raw format than a domain object or object graph.  The query mechanism would more-then-likely return primitives, such as `int Count(Query.Specification specification)` or perhaps return a list of *read model* instances.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, a repository has different meanings in different contexts - and many authors have their own interpretation. The way I understand them is from multiple perspectives:

- They abstract away underline storage type
- They can introduce interface closer to the domain model
- They represent a collection of objects and thus serve as aggregate
  in-memory storage(collection of related objects)
- They represent a transaction boundary for related objects.
- They can't contain duplicates - like sets.
- It is valid for the repository to contain only one object, without
  complex relations internally

So to answer your questions, repositories should contain collection related methods like add, remove, addAll, findByCriteria - instead of save, update, delete. They can return whole aggregate or parts of aggregates or some internal aggregate relation - it is dependent on your domain model and the way you want to represent objects

Answer (score 1):

Eric Evans coined "domain driven design" in 2003; so the right starting point for any definitions in that context is [his book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215).  He defines the repository pattern in chapter 6 ("Lifecycle of a Domain Object").

> A REPOSITORY represents all objects of a type as a conceptual set (usually emulated).  It acts like a collection, except with more elaborate querying ability.  Objects of the appropriate type are added and removed, and the machinery behind the repository inserts them or deletes them from the database.
>
> ...
>
> For each type of object that requires global access, create an object that can provide the illusion of an in-memory collection of all objects of that type.

The primary use case of a repository: given a key, return the correct root entity.  The repository implementation acts as a module, which hides your choice of persistence strategy  (see: [Parnas 1971](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/05/on-the-criteria-to-be-used-in-decomposing-systems-into-modules/)).